# HTML/CSS: Specify number of lines inside <span>

Tags: html, css

I have a PHP-Webapp and a span, that looks something like this:

`<span><?= $text ?></span>`

I would like to make sure, that the span has only one line. So if the text is too long, I would like to not show the last words. Can I do that using HTML/CSS? Or do I have to shorten the text with PHP/Javascript?

Comment: Do you want to delete the words or do you want something like `overflow:hidden;`?

Comment: I dont care. The words should just not appear, so that the whole text fits in one line. I know I could delete the last workds with PHP /Javascript, but I would rather have something more easy in HTML/CSS...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this? *(obviously you would set thewidth to whatever it needs to be on the page)*

The text-overflow: ellipsis is CSS3 and will only be supported in modern browsers, so in older ones you will get a nasty mid-letter/word cut off at the end.

```
span{display: block; width: 100px; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

Comment: Instead of height, you could also use: `word-wrap: break-word`

Comment: Instead of word-wrap: break-word, I used: white-space: nowrap and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend to you below code

```
span {
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;  // <- you can change rows number
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: `-webkit-line-clamp` seems to be a buggy legacy feature that corresponds to current standard `line-clamp` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough and not fully tested idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
p{
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
--></style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This span (<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>&hellip;) is always 200px width.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This proof of concept basically does this:

- Make the span a block level element so it can be assigned a width.
- Force the span to render in one line (given that the source string does not have `<br>` tags).
- Hide overflowed content.
- Fix margins and alignment so it stays at the same level than the parent element.

Improvements welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will do that:

```
function display_one_line($text) {
    $break = strpos($text, "\n");

    if ($break === false) {
        return $text;
    }

    return trim(substr($text, 0, $break));
}
```

Usage:

```
<span><?= display_one_line($text) ?></span>
```

but if you only need to do this one time, you can use this one-liner:

```
<span><?= (($break = strpos($text, "\n")) !== false ? substr($text, 0, $break) : $text) ?></span>
```