# Two line text finding in div

Tags: asp.net

I have a text to show in div. Now the condition is, this must not contains more then 2 lines. If it contains more then 2 lines then a link(Read More) should be presented as last two words in the second line to show the copmlete text.

**Query** - How to determine the text is of two lines only?

***Edit***
Two lines can have two cases.

1. New line symbol.
2. Virtual wrapping

Comment: Two lines mean contains NewLine symbol or considering visual text wrapping?

Comment: With a newline symbol it should be easy enough: just count the number of newline chars in the string, and clip the string off at the second. For virtual wrapping... you'd have to know the width of the page being displayed. Is javascript an option?

Comment: Similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142149/is-it-possible-to-wrap-lots-of-text-exactly-three-times-then-add-a-more-link/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count = Regex.Matches(input, Environment.NewLine).Count;
```

1. if the count is > 1 do your 'read more' logic
2. if the strings length is greater than twice the width allowed in the virtual wrapping, do your 'read more' logic.